# How to intialise objects in the array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to initialize objects in my ArrayList

The following is my code and what it does is that it receives an ArrayList, already defined in the main method. However, it is not executing the readInput method in the code below. readInput is a method declared in another class called customer that takes in keyboard input from the user. Its a complete class BTW. I believe that there is no object in the ArrayList at the moment as i have run some test to see whats the problem. Im new to using Arraylist. Therefoere i am unsure of how to solve this proble.
What custs.set(i, new customer()); does is actually to initialize the object in index.

```
public static void freeCustomer(ArrayList<customer> custs,
                                ArrayList<supplement>supps)
{
    for(int i=0;i<custs.size();i++)
    {

        custs.set(i, new customer());
        custs.get(i).readInput();
        for(int s=0;s<supps.size();s++)
        {
         supps.set(s, new supplement());
         supps.get(s).readInput();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW its also not executing the custs.set(i, new customer()) statement in the code. It stops at the for loop statement.

Comment: probably you did not initialize custs and supps before sending them to method. you can initialize `ArrayList<customer> custs = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Which line is it failing on and what is the error?

Comment: @JDelorean at the for loop. It just skips the statements in the for loop.

Comment: @xxlali i already initialize the custs and supps in the main method alr

Comment: @MdFairus You are correct to think that `custs` has 0 elements in it. Check how the list is populated or whether the correct object is passed as an arg.

Comment: @JDelorean currently the list is not populated. How do i populate it. I want to do in such a way that it uses a for loop and calls the method readInput from the customer class. However im not to sure how to do it in an array list style. Customer class currently contain the readInput method.

Comment: @JDelorean for simplicity sake, if i  use a normal array, the code would be something like this:      
public static void freeCustomer(customer[] customers, supplement[] supplements)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<customers.length;i++)
        {
            //Creating an instance of the customer object
            customers[i]=new customer();
            //Getting customer name and email address
            customers[i].readInput();
        } 
    }

Comment: @MdFairus You need to present how you initialize the list first. Depending on what you pass to `ArrayList` constructor will determine the number of elements in the list. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right,you want to add user input from a customer method.I would use add method.I just made a fast example of add method.From here you can expand to loops,etc.

```
 public static void freeCustomer(ArrayList<customer> custo,customer c)
{
 custo.add(new customer(c.readInput()));

 }


    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        ArrayList<customer> custo = new ArrayList<customer>();
        customer c=new customer("");

        freeCustomer(custo,c);


        }
    }
```